# Multiple overhead Symbols in Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, vector

I have fiddled with this for a while now without any real success, so if anyone could help me with this I'd be delighted.

I'd like to add multiple overhead symbols to a character in math mode. In particular, what I'd like is a harpoon symbol above a ring symbol above a character in math mode (semantically, a vector of (element with ring overhead)).

An MWE (plus my attempts) is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{harpoon} % required for overhead harpoon symbol

\begin{document}

\[
\mathring{\overrightharp{x}} % what I want in reverse order (I'd like harpoon above ring)
\]

\[
\overrightharp{\mathring{x}} % throws error (``missing $ inserted'')
\]

\end{document}
```

In order to be consistent with my remaining document, I'd like to keep both the ring as well as the harpoon symbol.
If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, I'd be very grateful!

(Additionally, can anyone explain why the nested code works in one way but not the other?)

Thanks,
Rance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of `\overrightharp` is typeset in text mode, so `\mathring` raises an error.

I think you're better served by `accents`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,accents}

\newcommand{\myvec}[1]{\accentset{\rightharpoonup}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\myvec{\mathring{a}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a visual comparison with the above and what you get from

```
\text{\overrightharp{$\mathring{a}$}}
```

(yes, that's what's required).

[image]