Can't Find Error for the Life of Me
I have this block of text in overleaf with an equation at the bottom and I cannot find why overleaf is failing to compile. Its saying I have a missing $ or { but I don't see an issue there. Overightharp is a package I imported and is working fine so that is not the issue. What's wrong here?
The stiffness matrix $\bf{K}$ of the physical reservoir 
is a function of $\overrightharp{x}$, where 
$\overrightharp{x}=\[x_1(t), x_(t),...,x_D(t)\]$ 
is a collection of all displacements for $D$ 
masses/nodes/neurons. Since the mass displacements 
vary as a function of time, the stiffness matrix 
dies as well. Consequently, the system's eigenvalues 
and eigenfrequencies vary as a function of time. Using 
the discretized time-scale $m=1,2,3,...,M$ with time-step 
$dt$, the system's eigenvalues $\overrightharp{\lambda}(m)$ 
and eigenfrequencies $\overrightharp{\omega}(m)$  are found 
analytically for each time step by solving the by solving the 
Quadratic Eigenvalue Problem (QEP) shown below, where 
$\overrightharp{v}(m)$ are the eigenvectors at each each 
time-step $m$. There are a total of $2D$ eigenvalues, unlike 
traditional eigenvalue problems where there are $D$ eigenvalues \cite{QEP}.

\begin{equation}
   \left(\bf{M} \overrightharp{\lambda^2}(m)+\bf{C}\overrightharp{\lambda}(m)
   +\bf{K}\right)\overrightharp{v}(m) = 0
\end{equation}


Welcome! Please provide code we can compile to reproduce the problem. Snippets are rarely useful. Note that \bf has been deprecated in LaTeX for a few decades now and ought not be used with this format. Comment out everything else in your document, if necessary, until you find the problem. It won't necessarily be on the line reported. That's just the first line at which the engine realises there's a problem. The actual cause could be earlier or in another file e.g. the citation.

\bf in a math environment may be the problem.  Change those to \mathbf and see if it makes a difference.  And off-topic: it's not a good idea to leave a blank line before a math display.

\bf  has not been defined by default in latex since 1993. article class defines it for compatibility with latex2.09,  but if you are using that definition your second two \bf do nothing as the scope of the first \bm lasts as far as the \right

The parameter of \overrightharp is typeset in text mode (see https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harpoon/harpoon.pdf), so using $\overrightharp{\lambda}$ doesn't work since it would be like writing \lambda in text. Instead you can use \overrightharp{$\lambda$}.
For example, change $\overrightharp{\lambda}(m)$ to \overrightharp{$\lambda$}$(m)$.
Edit: this works but the harpoon will be kind of ugly. The accents package probably works better, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426353/319442.

The passage ...{x}=\[x_1(t), x_(t),...,x_D(t)\] should also be throwing an error message. The OP probably may have meant to write ...{x}=\{x_1(t), x_(t),\dots,x_D(t)\}.
